# function type with ternary operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, gcc, ternary-operator

I try this code:

```
    int a=1;
    std::function<int (int, int)> getM = a?
    [](int x, int y) {
        return (x+y);
    } :
    [](int x, int y) {
        return (x*y);
    };


    cout<<getM(1,2);
```

In visual studio it gives an error:
error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'wmain::' to 'wmain::'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

In GCC it's compiled.  I suppose that GCC is the correct behaviour, but I'm not sure. What are other options to make this on VS2013?

Comment: There is a table of what's supported by VS at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx. I am not sure what would be a good work around for your problem.

Comment: I wanted to say VS was right, but man, those candidate operator functions.

Comment: @aschepler VS was wrong :) This should have converted both lambdas to function pointers. VS's problem is that their lambdas have *too many* conversion functions to function pointers, resulting in an ambiguity :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm it also doesn't build with VS 2015 update 3.

> What are other options?

Well, a standard if/else is always the alternative for any ternary operation:

```
std::function<int (int, int)> getM;;

if (a)
    getM = [](int x, int y) { return (x + y); };
else
    getM = [](int x, int y) { return (x * y); };
```